# Запись звука с аудиокарты

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

Добрый день. Скажите пожалуйста как правильно сделать запись звука с аудиокарты так, чтобы это можно было всё в потоке отправить по сети. Звук должен быть на уровне системы. То есть если в один момент воспроизводятся несколько звуков (фильм, музыка и игра какая), то все они должны быть записаны одновременно. Что-то на подобие стриминга. Пробовал CSCore, но пока дошёл только до записи с микрофона. А я хочу самой системы звуки записывать, это надо для передачи звука с компьютера на телефон по сети, своего рода беспроводные наушники.
Если в качестве девайса ему подсунуть динамики, то будет ошибка, если микрофон, то всё работает. Если кто знает, помогите.

```
        wasapiCapture = new WasapiCapture();
        wasapiCapture.Device = DeviceSelector.SelectedItem as MMDevice;
        server = new RemoteAudioServer();
        server.ClientAccepted += Server_ClientAccepted;
        server.StartService();
        wasapiCapture.Initialize();
        wasapiCapture.Start();
```

Comment: См. [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18812248/5045688). А [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4953218/5045688) пишут, что loopback поддерживается не всеми аудиокартами.

Comment: Хочу вам порекомендовать хорошую библиотеку для записи звука и проч. работы со звуком [NAudio](https://naudio.codeplex.com/)

Comment: В дополнение к выше сказанному статья [как записывать и воспроизводить звук одновременно](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.ru/2014/03/how-to-record-and-play-audio-at-same.html) должно вам помочь.